# iPad application having landscape mode only, issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        return NO;
} else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        return NO;
} else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape left detected!");
        return NO;
} else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape right detected!");
        return YES;
}
```

I am trying to implement an iPad app having landscape mode only. I set the Supported interface orientations as Landscape right mode in info.plist. WHen the application is started, the view is in Landscape mode itself. But when i added another view, such as Home view, after login, view is not rotated as landscape. It was in portrait mode. In the xib file also, i set it as landscape. I have included the above code in both Login and Home view controller.
But the home view is not rotating after  login.

Answer (score 0):

do this in each view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you dont have to write checks for each and every orientation. You can achieve this by simply using the following code in your viewController's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
```

Second can you provide more details on how actually you are adding more views. It will be more helpful to find the problem.

Comment: Hi, Can i know the difference of writing orientation code as return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); and that i mentioned above.

Comment: Both codes work exactly same but major difference is you can do all that in just one line of code what you are trying to do in multiple if statements.